# What is the syntax for a mongoose query where I just want one property's value?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am sending a query to mongoDB using mongoose. The collection is named Step. I want the result of this query to be an array of _id values, one per step. Currently I am getting all of the step objects in their entirety, because req.query isn't defined in this case.

service:

```
this.getSteps = function() {
  return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/step'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

controller:

```
readStep: function (req, res) {
    Step.find(req.query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the second parameter of the find query to '_id' to retrieve only the _id of the objects.

```
Step.find(req.query, '_id', function(err, result) {
```

This will return data like this:

```
[{_id: 123}, {_id: 234}]
```

If you want to get an array of the Step ids on their own, use the javascript map function like so

```
result = result.map(function(doc) {
    return doc._id;
});
```

which will give you an array like this:

```
[123, 234]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use query.select, something like as shown below:

```
Step.find(query).select({ "_id": 1}).then(....);
```

I'm not able to type much because I'm responding from my handheld.

Hope this help!